# SharePoint Designer Workflow Item Count

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have created SharePoint designer workflow 2013. I am using REST API to fetch records with filter query as below

```
[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]_api/lists/getbytitle('[%Workflow Context:List Name%]')/items?$select=Title,ItemId,Reaction,Flag&$filter=Flag eq '1'
```

Now I am using Item Count Action to count the Results but it always give me zero. Kindly help me to solve the issue

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing web in your endpoint  `_api/web/` .

It's helpful to output the rest api endpoint for troubleshooting so you could test in browser.

My test demo:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Still Same, i added _api/web/

I tested in browser without web URL was giving output

Comment: attach my test demo for your reference.