# how to count number of items in workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint

I want to create a Sharepoint workflow in 2013 which will send the email to Assigned users-
If there are 5 items for A user, 10 for B users and 15 for C user then email will be triggered to A,B and C with respective count of items.
Can anyone please share any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Call rest api in workflow to get items based on user, [demo to call rest api in SharePoint workflow](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

Then

[SharePoint Designer Workflow Item Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322244/sharepoint-designer-workflow-item-count)

[rest api to filter user field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232691/unable-to-filter-sharepoint-rest-api-according-to-person-or-group-field)

Comment: I used the same thing but Rest call is showing me unexpected error.